# Rails 5 Mysterious Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I followed [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users)
I'm currently on chapter 14, when I tried to implement follow feature, I got a mysterious problem.

I just create 2 `users` (`first` and `second`)
And then tried `first.follow(second)`
as I know, it just touched on `relationships` table, and didn't on users table.
But my code failed on validation

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}, allow: nil
```

this validation is only on User model. It's so weird. I don't know why.

Please help!

Comment: Can you add your User and Relationship models code here?

Comment: what is `allow: nil` for? did you mean `allow_nil: true` ? if so, then that would be in conflict with `presence: true`

Comment: also, if your code failed on validation, please post your error here, its instrumental in debugging your code. Always, always read carefully your error messages